# git didn't push empty folders

Tags: git

I init folder. Added all files commit them and than push them. Everything was looking fine...but i am missing some files and folder.

To example my .gitignore file

```
web/images/uploaded_profile_pictures/*
```

But there should be uploaded_profile_pictures folder... how to write it in .gitignore to ignore ONLY the content of the folder.. and keep the folder?

And second problem... why is there missing content???

After push

[image]

Comment: you can't commit an empty folder, because internally git does not think in folders and files, but in one big binary blob

Comment: @JWhy answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 10):

There can't be folders without files in Git repositories, Git will always ignore empty folders (or folders that contain only ignored files). A common workaround is to create placeholder files in empty directories that you want to include in your Git repository.

```
touch web/images/uploaded_profile_pictures/.empty
git add web/images/uploaded_profile_pictures/.empty
```

Now for the `.gitignore`:

```
web/images/uploaded_profile_pictures/*
!web/images/uploaded_profile_pictures/.empty
# or just
!.empty
```

This will make Git ignore all files in that folder except of `.empty`, allowing you to add the folder to the repo.

For the second question: What kind of files are missing? Are those just random ones?

Comment: Hm... i didn't know that.. thx. Hm.. i dont think so... the missing files( dont know if all of them) was first somehow ... as submodules of git.. but than i removed all .git folders from this folders... git status is showing (clean) and pushed tham to server... but i dont know why they are missing...

Comment: This should accepted answer. Thanks friend.

Answer (score 2):

As @Uroc327 mentioned in his comment, git doesn't handle "folders and files" but instead it uses "content".

This means that an empty folder is simply non existent to git.

This is a common problem, and the simplest solution is to add some "fake content" (an empty file) to a folder.

As @jwhy said, you could create a file named `empty`.
A more elegant approach (in my opinion) would be having in the folder `web/images/uploaded_profile_pictures` a file named `.gitignore` which contains the following:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Comment: okay i know that now thx, but the main problem is now the missing files( dont know if all of them) was first somehow ... as submodules of git.. but than i removed all .git folders from this folders... git status is showing (clean) and pushed tham to server... but i dont know why they are missing...